# For Firebase AB testing the number of users are 0

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-ab-testing

I am currently learning about firebase ab testing. I dont have my app in production ( not deployed on the google play store). So to get users for my app can i use app release & distribution by firebase , (send apk file to testers in my organisation) . Is there any alternative way ?
Could anyone please help me regarding this , since I am just a beginner starting to learn firebase ab testing.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.